# Facebook Api: score for all users

Tags: ios, facebook, api, unity-game-engine

Can help me. In my Unity project for IOS i need to show with graph.facebook scores for ALL people who played in a game.

In graph Explorer for my app i write: "app/scores/" - he return score only my friends who played in app

Or if i write "100007769684111/scores" and if he is my friend, when return a number, but if i deleted this boy from my friends, then graph Explorer return null

How can i get scores for all peoples from my app if also not my friends

P.s. Sorry my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
The app/scores only returns friends scores.